# setting DefaultValue of UpdateParameter gives error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm using the following snippit of code to update an entry:

```
Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
    With SqlDataSource1
        .UpdateParameters("id").DefaultValue = Request.QueryString("id")
        .UpdateParameters("pageContent").DefaultValue = edittor.Content
        .Update()
    End With
End Sub
```

The problem is that is says

```
.UpdateParameters("id").DefaultValue
```

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I've used it this way before (I think).  Could somebody please explain why this is messed up **OR**, because I've noticed that most people do it straight in the SQL, how to do this the correct way (i.e. updating an entry in my table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the best solution but you can try this one. For this you should not include that parameter in .aspx page otherwise it will throw an error.

**First Method:**

```
Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
           Dim id As New Parameter
        id.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        id.Name = "ID"
        id.DefaultValue = RubricID

        If SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters.Contains(id) = True Or SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters.Count = 1 Then
            SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters.Item("ID").DefaultValue = RubricID
        Else
            SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters.Add(id)
        End If
        SqlDataSource1.Update()     
End Sub
```

**Second Method:**

Specify parameters OnUpdating Event of SqlDataSource

```
   Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
    SqlDataSource1.Update()   
    End Sub

Protected Sub SqlDataSource1_Updating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs) Handles SqlDataSource1.Updating
       Dim ID = New SqlParameter("@ID", CType(Page.RouteData.Values("id"), Int16))
            e.Command.Parameters.Add(ID)
    End Sub
```

Comment: I'm confused as to what I am supposed to do with these code-snippets.  Could you provide me some context to apply them (i.e. code surrounding this to show me where it all goes).

Comment: Check my update with more code.  I hope that helps. Go for the second one.  In that when SqlDataSource1.update() is triggered it will fire SqldataSource1_Updating event.  Then it will capture all  your parameters.